extend selection till end of file not working
I'm using Sublime Text and Visual Studio Code (or rather, I'm using its open-source clone Codium) on
Ubuntu 24.04, with a French AZERTY keyboard.
For both of those apps, I've tried to find a shortcut for "extend the current existing selection till the end
of the file" and did not find anything.
Ctrl+Shift+end just leaves the selected region and goes to the end of the file.
Update If it matters, here is the French keyboard layout I'm using (written by other people than me, as indicated in the credits) :
// Unicode French derivative
// Loose refactoring of the historic Linux French keyboard layout
//
// Copyright © 2006-2008 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
//
// Credits (fr-latin1, fr-latin0, fr-latin9)
//   © 199x-1996 René Cougnenc ✝
//   © 1997-2002 Guylhem Aznar <clavier @ externe.net>
//   © 2003-2006 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
//
// ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┲━━━━━━━━━┓
// │ ³ ¸ │ 1  ̨ │ 2 É │ 3 ˘ │ 4 — │ 5 – │ 6 ‑ │ 7 È │ 8 ™ │ 9 Ç │ 0 À │ ° ≠ │ + ± ┃ ⌫ Retour┃
// │ ² ¹ │ & ˇ │ é ~ │ " # │ ' { │ ( [ │ - | │ è ` │ _ \ │ ç ^ │ à @ │ ) ] │ = } ┃  arrière┃
// ┢━━━━━┷━┱───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┺━┳━━━━━━━┫
// ┃       ┃ A Æ │ Z Â │ E ¢ │ R Ê │ T Þ │ Y Ÿ │ U Û │ I Î │ O Œ │ P Ô │ ¨ ˚ │ £ Ø ┃Entrée ┃
// ┃Tab ↹  ┃ a æ │ z â │ e € │ r ê │ t þ │ y ÿ │ u û │ i î │ o œ │ p ô │ ^ ~ │ $ ø ┃   ⏎   ┃
// ┣━━━━━━━┻┱────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┺┓      ┃
// ┃        ┃ Q Ä │ S „ │ D Ë │ F ‚ │ G ¥ │ H Ð │ J Ü │ K Ï │ L Ŀ │ M Ö │ % Ù │ µ  ̄ ┃      ┃
// ┃Maj ⇬   ┃ q ä │ s ß │ d ë │ f ‘ │ g ’ │ h ð │ j ü │ k ï │ l ŀ │ m ö │ ù ' │ * ` ┃      ┃
// ┣━━━━━━━┳┹────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┲┷━━━━━┻━━━━━━┫
// ┃       ┃ > ≥ │ W “ │ X ” │ C ® │ V ← │ B ↑ │ N → │ ? … │ . . │ / ∕ │ § − ┃             ┃
// ┃Shift ⇧┃ < ≤ │ w « │ x » │ c © │ v ⍽ │ b ↓ │ n ¬ │ , ¿ │ ; × │ : ÷ │ ! ¡ ┃Shift ⇧      ┃
// ┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━┷━┳━━━┷━━━┱─┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───┲━┷━━━━━╈━━━━━┻━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━┛
// ┃       ┃       ┃       ┃ ␣         Espace fine insécable ⍽ ┃       ┃       ┃       ┃
// ┃Ctrl   ┃Meta   ┃Alt    ┃ ␣ Espace       Espace insécable ⍽ ┃AltGr ⇮┃Menu   ┃Ctrl   ┃
// ┗━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┹───────────────────────────────────┺━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┛
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "oss" {

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
    include "nbsp(level4n)"
    include "keypad(oss)"

    name[Group1]="French (alt.)";

    // First row
    key <TLDE>  { [      twosuperior,    threesuperior,          onesuperior,          dead_cedilla ] }; // ² ³ ¹ ¸
    key <AE01>  { [        ampersand,                1,           dead_caron,           dead_ogonek ] }; // & 1 ˇ ˛
    key <AE02>  { [           eacute,                2,           asciitilde,                Eacute ] }; // é 2 ~ É
    key <AE03>  { [         quotedbl,                3,           numbersign,            dead_breve ] }; // " 3 # ˘
    key <AE04>  { [       apostrophe,                4,            braceleft,             0x1002014 ] }; // ' 4 { — (tiret cadratin)
    key <AE05>  { [        parenleft,                5,          bracketleft,             0x1002013 ] }; // ( 5 [ – (tiret demi-cadratin)
    key <AE06>  { [            minus,                6,                  bar,             0x1002011 ] }; // - 6 | ‑ (tiret insécable)
    key <AE07>  { [           egrave,                7,                grave,                Egrave ] }; // è 7 ` È
    key <AE08>  { [       underscore,                8,            backslash,             trademark ] }; // _ 8 \ ™
    key <AE09>  { [         ccedilla,                9,          asciicircum,              Ccedilla ] }; // ç 9 ^ Ç
    key <AE10>  { [           agrave,                0,                   at,                Agrave ] }; // à 0 @ À
    key <AE11>  { [       parenright,           degree,         bracketright,              notequal ] }; // ) ° ] ≠
    key <AE12>  { [            equal,             plus,           braceright,             plusminus ] }; // = + } ±

    // Second row
    key <AD01>  { [                a,                A,                   ae,                    AE ] }; // a A æ Æ
    key <AD02>  { [                z,                Z,          acircumflex,           Acircumflex ] }; // z Z â Â
    key <AD03>  { [                e,                E,             EuroSign,                  cent ] }; // e E € ¢
    key <AD04>  { [                r,                R,          ecircumflex,           Ecircumflex ] }; // r R ê Ê
    key <AD05>  { [                t,                T,                thorn,                 THORN ] }; // t T þ Þ
    key <AD06>  { [                y,                Y,           ydiaeresis,            Ydiaeresis ] }; // y Y ÿ Ÿ
    key <AD07>  { [                u,                U,          ucircumflex,           Ucircumflex ] }; // u U û Û
    key <AD08>  { [                i,                I,          icircumflex,           Icircumflex ] }; // i I î Î
    key <AD09>  { [                o,                O,                   oe,                    OE ] }; // o O œ Œ
    key <AD10>  { [                p,                P,          ocircumflex,           Ocircumflex ] }; // p P ô Ô
    key <AD11>  { [  dead_circumflex,   dead_diaeresis,           dead_tilde,        dead_abovering ] }; // ^ ¨ ˜ ˚
    key <AD12>  { [           dollar,         sterling,               oslash,                Oslash ] }; // $ £ ø Ø

    // Third row
    key <AC01>  { [                q,                Q,           adiaeresis,            Adiaeresis ] }; // q Q ä Ä
    key <AC02>  { [                s,                S,               ssharp,    doublelowquotemark ] }; // s S ß „
    key <AC03>  { [                d,                D,           ediaeresis,            Ediaeresis ] }; // d D ë Ë
    key <AC04>  { [                f,                F,  leftsinglequotemark,    singlelowquotemark ] }; // f F ‘ ‚
    key <AC05>  { [                g,                G, rightsinglequotemark,                   yen ] }; // g G ’ ¥
    key <AC06>  { [                h,                H,                  eth,                   ETH ] }; // h H ð Ð
    key <AC07>  { [                j,                J,           udiaeresis,            Udiaeresis ] }; // j J ü Ü
    key <AC08>  { [                k,                K,           idiaeresis,            Idiaeresis ] }; // k K ï Ï
    key <AC09>  { [                l,                L,            0x1000140,             0x100013F ] }; // l L ŀ Ŀ
    key <AC10>  { [                m,                M,           odiaeresis,            Odiaeresis ] }; // m M ö Ö
    key <AC11>  { [           ugrave,          percent,           dead_acute,                Ugrave ] }; // ù % ´ Ù
    key <BKSL>  { [         asterisk,               mu,           dead_grave,           dead_macron ] }; // * µ ` ¯

    // Fourth row
    key <LSGT>  { [             less,          greater,        lessthanequal,      greaterthanequal ] }; // < > ≤ ≥
    key <AB01>  { [                w,                W,        guillemotleft,   leftdoublequotemark ] }; // w W « “
    key <AB02>  { [                x,                X,       guillemotright,  rightdoublequotemark ] }; // x X » ”
    key <AB03>  { [                c,                C,            copyright,            registered ] }; // c C © ®
    key <AB04>  { [                v,                V,            0x100202F,             leftarrow ] }; // v V ⍽ ← (espace fine insécable)
    key <AB05>  { [                b,                B,            downarrow,               uparrow ] }; // b B ↓ ↑
    key <AB06>  { [                n,                N,              notsign,            rightarrow ] }; // n N ¬ →
    key <AB07>  { [            comma,         question,         questiondown,             0x1002026 ] }; // , ? ¿ …
    key <AB08>  { [        semicolon,           period,             multiply,             0x10022C5 ] }; // ; . × ⋅
    key <AB09>  { [            colon,            slash,             division,             0x1002215 ] }; // : / ÷ ∕
    key <AB10>  { [           exclam,          section,           exclamdown,             0x1002212 ] }; // ! § ¡ −
};

Attempting to input the combination in Codium using alternatively either RSHIFT or LSHIFT, RSHIFT is ignored, and LSHIFT simply extends the selection by one character.
CTRL+SHIFT+END is correctly mapped to cursorBottomSelect in Codium's global keybindings file.
Also, trying to reimpose CTRL+SHIFT+END as a user-defined key binding does not change anything.

CTRL + Shift + END works for me in VSCode. I'm using an Italian (QWERTY) keyboard (I don't think the keyboard layout really matters though). Are you sure you haven't  somehow overriden keybindings.json? Although judging from the description of the problem it looks like SHIFT is ignored entirely, as CTRL + END is supposed to move the cursor at the end of the file. Does Shift otherwise work?

Can you post the contents of ~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json? I'm unfamiliar with Sublime, but if you're sure CTRL + Shift + END is supposed to work in Sublime the same it does in VSCode then that file is probably irrelevant

As a workaround for the time being you could rebind the combination to something else by putting {"key":"ctrl+shift+end","command":"cursorBottomSelect","when":"textInputFocus"} in the user-defined keybindings file (changing ctrl+shift+end accordingly), although I understand it probably wouldn't be as convenient.

@kos I should have done that myself, thx for doing my job. Have to go now, will be back in a few hours to try your suggestion

Cheers, no problem at all. It took less than a minute. I also removed my comments that were not relevant anymore; the only missing bit to exclude Codium as the culprit would be confirming that the user-defined keybindings aren't overriding the global keybindings, I suggest you add that information to the question once you've figured out whether that's the case

@kos I did as you suggested with user-defined key bindings, but I noticed something strange : when I create a ~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json file it is ignored by Codium when I ask it for "user-defined key bindings", Codium says it can't find the file, and asks me to create a file at the very root of the system, /keybindings.json. It seems obvious that user-specific preferences should be stored inside that user's home directory, not at the root ...

I installed Codium, started it, hit CTRL + Shift + P ant typed in "keyboard", then chose "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)", which opened a (freshly created I guess) ~/.config/VSCodium/User/keybindings.json in the editor. What if happens if you do exactly as I did?

@kos When I do exactly as you said, it does freshly create this file for me as expected, before I was doing slightly different which is why it didn't work.

@kos I mention and thank you in my answer.

There's no need to thank me in the answer, but thanks :) I'm glad that you figured it out!

I eventually found out where the problem came from. Nothing to do with software, it's just that my (French) keyboard has no
separate "end" key, and it has in fact two keys labelled "end" ("fin" in French) as shown below :

The 'right arrow' key shown above is called RIGHT by Ubuntu software (even though it's labeled "end" on my keyboard) while
the 'Numerical 1' is indeed called "end", and everything works fine when I use this key for END, both in Codium
or Sublime Text.
Before this realization, I only used this "Right arrow" as an RIGHT key, and I hadn't noticed that there was another key labelled "end".
Thanks again to @kos who unwittingly set me in the right direction. After he suggested that I redefine inside Codium references, it was Codium's nice
interface that made me realize that this "Right arrow" key was in fact a RIGHT :

